# Google Spreadsheet Determine lowest number in a row of cells

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, comparison

I'm new to this site for the main purpose that I plan to pursue a career in programming. I've landed my first job at an engineering company who is asking me to set up a system in which they can easily determine the time between a job being filed, and it's completion. We're using spreadsheet docs right now to accomplish certain pieces of this.

I'm looking to create a custom function in Google Docs that will allow me to traverse the array of values in row C and then compare it with a number that the function was called with, compare the number to the number in the array and give me which one is the smaller number. **EDIT: The function will be called on another sheet called "parsed data" located in the same project file.** It's purpose is to automatically file the order number of a current project (just for the sake of being organized) All the other functions I plan to implement will be based off of this order number being correct.

So far, I've gathered this much (I'm learning this on the fly because I still lack experience, so bear with me.)

```
{
/**created by Alexander Bickford for use at Double E Company
*sorts through a range of values to determine the lowest next value
*returns lowest determined value of next cell
*/  
//List Of To Be Implemented Functions
// sheet.appendRow 

function setValue(num)
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet('parsed data');
    var ss = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var myRange = ss.getRange("C:C").getValues();
    newValues = [];
    for(i=1;i<=myRange;i++)    //Loop to traverse the C range and find the lowest value.
    {
       if(num<=range[3][i])
       {
       }
       else 
         num = range[3][i];
    } 
    return num;
  }
}
```

when I call the function in the spreadsheet, I'm getting an error passed that says: 
**error: ReferenceError: "SPREADSHEET_ID_GOES_HERE" is not defined. (line 8, file "Code")**

Google predefines some functions at the top that look like this:

```
/**

 * Retrieves all the rows in the active spreadsheet that contain data and logs the
 * values for each row.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet

function readRows() {                       <---Line 8 in the file
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    Logger.log(row);
  }
};


 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the readRows() function specified above.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Read Data",
    functionName : "readRows"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};
End Code I don't need */
```

I assume it has something to do with the earlier lines (I pointed out line 8). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var myRange = ss.getRange("C:C").getValues();
newValues = [];
for(i=1;i<=myRange.length;i++)
{
    Logger.log(myRange[i]);   
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the lines a bit in detail for me? I'm very new to this and trying to orient myself to how each line is executing. Also, I should have mentioned previously that I am trying to acquire the information from a different sheet located in the same project file. for instance, my sheet that I want to look at is called "parsed data" and I want to throw the information I pull from it into a file titled "report status".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems like you have a few problems.

1. You seem to be mixing up "sheets" with "spreadsheet", and your redundant declaration of "ss" as a variable is bound to cause you some problems.
2. You seem to be passing in arguments to the incorrect methods. I had this same problem when working with the Google App script earlier. It took a lot of poking around Google's Documentation (which you should really take a look at: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). You seem to be making the same mistake I did, coding by analogy. looking at Google's sample code and trying to replicate is bound to bump you into some trouble.

Some useful advice:

1. The most confusing thing to wrap your head around is the structure: spreadsheet>>sheet>>range, you have to explicitely deal with the one's on top before moving to the one's on the bottom.
2. Remove the 'parsed data' argument from getActiveSpreadsheet(), it should be blank. What you want to use is "getSheetByName("parsed data")" and pass that into a sheet variable.
3. In your for loop, you also need to use the ".length" method, or use the ".getLastRow()" method with a sheet object to find the last row in your sheet.

Your code might look something like this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("parsed data");
var endRowNumber = sheet1.getLastRow();
//insert rest of code
```

Comment: I continued writing other functions today for this project of mine, I've noticed what you're talking about, but I appreciate you explaining it.